# PHP Show Differences

Tags: php, arrays

I have two strings:

```
$stringA = "1,2,3,4";
$stringB = "1,2,4,5";
```

I want to pick out the values from `$stringB` that are not in `$stringA`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

A combination of explode and array_diff should get you there.

```
array_diff(explode(',', $stringB), explode(',', $stringA));
```

Comment: How can I display the results in a nice format instead of Array()?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you have to switch `$stringA` and `$stringB`. I think the OP wants all the values that are not in `$stringA`.

Comment: There is var_dump, not sure what type of output you are looking for.

Comment: You are right they need to be switched, but how can I echo the results in a nice format instead of Array()?

Comment: @John Norton: You could join them again, using `$str = implode(' ', $result);` or loop over the array and print the values.

Comment: Output such as (words that are different):

Word
Word
Word

Comment: It works except that it displays the last value as not in the first string even though it is...

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` both arrays and use `array_diff()` to compute differential array.

Answer (score 0):

http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/

That should help you out ...